# Enable application framework settings in WPF projects?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

What it is the option **Enable application framework** that I found in Visual Studio under VB.NET WPF projects Application settings?

I found it enabled by default and the `"Shutdown mode"` configured as `"On last windows close"`. But for me is not really clear what does it mean that setting and also the other settings listed in that combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means if you have an application that has multiple forms, the application terminates when the last form of that application has been closed. It doesn't matter which form is the last form you close. If you close all forms that belong to that application the application terminates.

**"When Startup Form Closes"** means that the application terminates when the form that is listed in the **"Startup from:"** Combobox gets closed. This means if you still have forms open but close the form that was set as your startup form, all other forms get closed aswell and your appliction terminates.