# What does it mean to "Enable Application Framework" for a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, application-framework

I'm creating a WPF application in VB.Net. I am trying to decide where my startup code should go. I seem to have two choices:

1. Leave the "Enable Application Framework" box checked and choose a "Startup URI" from among the application's windows.
2. Uncheck "Enable Application Framework" and choose to startup in my own Sub Main.

What are the implications of enabling or disabling the application framework, and why does the application framework restrict my choice of startup options?

-TC

Comment: The startup option part of this question is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816744/3195477

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable application framework settings in WPF projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725155/enable-application-framework-settings-in-wpf-projects)

Answer (score 7):

The Visual Studio magazine has [an article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/enable-the-application-framework-in-vb.aspx) about this.  Here's an excerpt.

> Visual Basic supports an "Application Framework" that makes it easier
>   to manage the startup, shutdown, and exception management of an
>   application. You enable or disable the application framework with a
>   check box in the Project Properties. The application framework is part
>   of the work Visual Basic does to make your development easier.